# Question about Stepper Motors

Tags: emf

I have a need to sometimes manually turn the lead screw on a stepper motor controlled CNC system (which I have not purchased yet). So IF I put a switch in the wires of the stepper motor and open the switch manually, is the motor shaft free to turn with out much resistance?

Anyone???

---

Thanks for the answer.

The "position" of the motor and/or lead screw, is irrelevant to the motor controls. IE:

All I want the motor to do is:

1. Turn a "lead-screw" clockwise when I press a given button, UNTIL I release the button.
2. Turn the same "lead-screw counter-clockwise, when I press another button, UNTIL I release the button.
3. Adjust a "speed" knob, to control the motor's speed when it is moving; from very fast to very slow; and even stop when the control is completely counter-clockwise.
4. Turn a switch off which will remove all control to the motor; so I can turn the shaft manually without resistance, whenever I do not want the fence to be under control of the motor.

That is ALL I need. (Note: My table saw fence has an electronic "readout"; which tells me exactly where the fence is at all times. I do not need any of the motor's controls to know or show me this.)

I will watch the readout while I am controlling the motor in the above steps; and when the fence gets to the desired distance from the blade: I will stop it. I will do the above every time I want to electrically move the fence to another position.

It is that simple. Hope you understand.

What do I need to purchase? HOW do I connect the required devices (to do the above). And how do I program the Arduino to do same.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do that, but then the control logic will lose track of the actual position of the motor.

It would be better to provide manual "jog" inputs to the controller so that you can make the adjustments you need while allowing the system to track them.

Comment: Responding to your edit -- that isn't [tag:CNC] at all; that's just manual control with electric drive. If you do purchase an electric drive, you simply need to switch off its power to "release" the motor for manual drive. It really isn't clear what your actual design question for us is -- perhaps you want to ask this in [DIY.SE](https://diy.stackexchange.com/)?